# Big O Notation: The sum of function body

Tags: algorithm, big-o

If a function body invokes 3 different functions, all of the order `O(n)`, how do I calculate the order of the outer (containing) function? Yes, this is homework, and I've surprisingly failed to find a relevant example in the textbook, nor the slides of our recent lectures.

```
private void bigFunction(){
    smallFunction1();   // O(n)
    smallFunction2();   // O(n)
    smallFunction3();   // O(n)
} // Now what does this result in?
```

My initial thought is `O(n)`, but I want to be certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. The cost of doing any constant number of O(n) operations is O(n).

Specifically, O(n) × O(1) = O(n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice to hear! I still fail to grasp how it can be the case, though. I am new to algorithms and Big O notation, but if I understand correctly, an order is a means to define the resource/time usage of a given piece of code. If that is true, then saying that a function calling 1x O(n) function and a function calling, say, 15x O(n) functions have the same resource/time usage doesn't sound right.. Maybe beyond the scope of this question, though. :)

Comment: @krystah: Big-O is like a ballpark estimate for how long your function will take to run. The downside is that we "hide" constants from it. So O(1,000,000 n) is the same as O(5 n) because of this. It's just a nuance of Big-O, because it assumes that n itself is already much, much, much bigger than any of the constants!

Comment: More accurately - big-O notation measures the rate at which a function grows. A function whose runtime is O(n) will have a runtime that roughly grows linearly. The sum of any constant number of linear functions is itself a linear function, which is why O(1) x O(n) = O(n).

Comment: O() notation is specifically designed to factor out "the constant factor", because there is no other way to separate the performance characteristics of the algorithm from the performance of the machine it runs on, or from different ways of describing the same algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

3 x O(n) = O(n)  since we are trying to find time complexity, biggest complexity will be the answer, O(n) is the biggest in that algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep in mind the definition of big-oh:

> A function f(x) is said to be O(g(n)) if there are numbers K and T
>   (which you can of course choose freely) such that for all x > T, f(x)
>   < K * g(x).

Of particular importance is the fact that you are free to select *any* K that fits the bill, not just the smallest K that does. It is this property that leads to g(n) always being shown as not having any constant factors: the following two scenarios are completely equivalent:

```
f(x) = x, g(n) = 2n, K = 1
f(x) = x, g(n) = 4n, K = 1/2
```

Since you can make g have any constant factor you like simply by selecting K appropriately, in practice we do not bother and always treat g as always having no constant factor.

At this point it should be clear that O(g(n)) + O(g(n)) is still O(g(n)), because for the sum you can simply choose "double the usual" value for K and still have the same form for g(n). Therefore the sum of any *constant* number of O(n) functions is still O(n).

Answer (score 0):

The best way of being really sure of something like this is to construct a proof based on the definition, quoted in @Jon's answer:

```
A function f(x) is said to be O(g(n)) if there are numbers 
K and T such that for all x > T, f(x) < K * g(x).
```

Let f_1(n) be the time for smallFunction1(), f_2(n) for smallFunction2(), and f_3(n) for smallFunction3(), all in a size n problem.

Because f_1(n) is O(n), there exist K_1 and T_1 such that, for all n > T_1, f_1(n) < K_1 * n.
Similarly, there exists K_2, T_2, K_3, and T_3 such that, for all n > T_2, f_2(n) < K_2 * n and for all n > T_3, f_3(n) < K_3 * n.

Let K equal K_1 + K_2 + K_3 and let T equal max(T_1, T_2, T_3). Then for all n > T, f_1(n) < K_1 * n, f_2(n) < K_2 * n, f_3(n) < K_3 * n.

The time to run the three functions consecutively, f_1(n) + f_2(n) + f_3(n), is less than K_1 * n + K_2 * n + K_3 * n = (K_1 + K_2 + K_3) * n = K * n, so the total time is O(n).